# Reference about torus

Tags: calculus, general-topology

I am a beginner and start to read about torus.

Could you please give me some reference which mentioned about torus in real and complex spaces?

I prefer a beginner book and relating to calculus.

Thank you for your help and understanding.

Comment: I think you probably mean "reference" (source) not "referee" (umpire).

Comment: In http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Torus.html you can find a very good first presentation and you will also have a good bibliography about torus.